# K on and K off in reverse reaction kinetics

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to code for a reverse reaction in biology - I have already done that by taking inspiration from a sample code pasted below. What I don't understand is how is the association rate constant (Kb in the code) and dissociation constant (Ku in the code) are affecting the forward and backward reactions in this code. Are they affecting the speed of movement of the products after they are formed? Are they affecting the speed with which they are formed? I want the Ku to affect affinity for substrates to form a product, and Ku to affect time to dissociate for products. The product is a complex formation of two substrates.

Also, why do they multiple Kb by 2? To slow the product complex down or speed it up? It should slow down due to increase in mass.

```
breed [reactants reactant]    ;; reactants are green, products are red breed [products product]

to setup   clear-all   set-default-shape reactants "molecule1"   set-default-shape products "molecule2"   create-reactants number
    [ set color green
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]   reset-ticks end

to go   ask turtles
    [ rt random-float 10 - random-float 10  ;; wander around randomly
      fd 1 ]   ask turtles
    [ ifelse (breed = reactants)
        [ react-forward ]  ; reactants
        [ react-backward ] ; products
    ]   tick end

to react-forward   if (any? other reactants-here) and
     ;; multiply Kb by 2 because 2 molecules are involved
     random-float 1000 < (Kb * 2)
    [ ask one-of other reactants-here
        [ die ]
      set breed products
      set color red ] end

to react-backward   if (random-float 1000) < Ku
    [ set breed reactants    ;; change back to reactant
      set color green
      ;; then split into two reactants
      hatch 1 [ set heading random 360 ] ] end
```

Comment: These parameters Ku and Kb affect the probability that a reaction occurs - any influence on speed of the reaction is indirect. That is, if the constant is increased, then probability is higher and reaction occurs more often and therefore is faster. They have no effect on movement speed.

Comment: Thanks. And would you know why are these constants multiplied by two for forward reaction?

Comment: The effect of multiplying by 2 is to make it twice as likely to occur. The person who wrote the code says that's because 2 molecules are involved, so presumably the coder thinks that doubling the probability of the reaction is an appropriate thing to do. But it seems odd because each of the reactants will have a chance to institute a reaction anyway (due to `all turtles`).